# Can't enable SketchUp Add on

Tags: add-on, import, customization, dae

I see the checkbox for the SketchUp add-on in the preferences, but cannot enable it.

Using Blender 3.1 and Sketch Up Pro 2022
Add on: SketchUp Importer 0.23.0

Please help, thanks a lot[image]

Comment: Hello, could you explain the process you used to install it ? Did you unzip the file before installing it as an addon ? If yes, you shouldn't have,

Comment: I've checked this against 3.1 and it works for me.  As @Gorgious suggests, the correct steps are 1) download `sketchup_importer.zip`. 2) start blender. 3) Edit preferences and go to add-ons. 4) select _install_.  You have to wait a bit though it seems to take nearly a minute for it to be ready to install.  Did you follow those steps or do something else?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers!I just tried it again in the same way you said - unfortunately still the same result. Cannot enable the checkbox..Any ideas?

Comment: Check if there is any message printed out when you open the console with Window > Toggle System Console and copy/paste it in the question

Comment: Last login: Wed Mar 30 14:12:48 on ttys000
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender ; exit;
ADBKMHN-HRWJ1G9:~ di57pam$ /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender ; exit;
Read prefs: /Users/di57pam/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.1/config/userpref.blend


Is this what you meant? Using mac - there is no Toggel System Control, have to open Terminal Blender.

Comment: Have you Sketchup in the same computer? because the plug-in depend on that.

Comment: from what i can see, that sketchup_importer.zip offered at the RedHaloStudio repo is targeted to windows machines. you might need to run the python setup script in one of the other deliverables. i tried just importing the original python script from (url)[https://github.com/heikkisa/blender-import-sketchup] which recognises the plugin (and can be enabled) but doesnt show up in the import menu (probably because it was made a while back and might not be compatible anymore with newer Blender versions).

Comment: the process to install on mac seems to require files from the sketchup developer API (signup required). [https://github.com/martijnberger/pyslapi]. the setup fails without the API.

Comment: for mac users, you can try this build: https://github.com/reyem/Sketchup_Importer/releases/tag/v0.23.0 but as the repo says its minimal tested (Monteray), and altho it appeared to install and enable for me (on Big Sur), it didnt show up as an option in import file menu.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? I am having the same issue, the version provided by jsky is not working, throwing an error once I try to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Looked on the github page of the addon and there are many issues open about this.

However user 'helsharif' posted a link to this addon:
https://github.com/RedHaloStudio/Sketchup_Importer/releases

Comment: So any success?

Comment: The addon I linked works for me. I'm able to import .skp files and they all look okay. I don't know why the "standard" addon doesn't work but this one is a good alternative. Just make sure to remove the 'old' addon before installing this one.