# Problem with import_sketchup.py on MAC

Tags: add-on, import

Like many others I am having difficulties using the import_sketchup.py on a Macintosh. I tried it for the first time a few months ago and I couldn´t even enable the add-o; exactly like it is described in this post: [Can´t enable Ketchup add-on](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258927/cant-enable-sketchup-add-on) Today I decided to try it once again and for my surprise I was able to tick the little square and enable import_sketchup.py! But unfortunately the option of importing Sketchup is not showing when I go to File>import (See print-screen).  I followed the instructions for [this page](https://github.com/heikkisa/blender-import-sketchup?tab=readme-ov-file) and downloaded the .py file [here](https://github.com/heikkisa/blender-import-sketchup/blob/master/src/import_sketchup.py)
[image: import not showing and add-on enable]

Did I miss anything? Hans anyone managed to import Sketchup into blender?

Thanks a lot  ahead.

I am new in this forum, I was not allowed post this question as a comment with the other post I mentioned above.

Comment: The files that you link to in your question were all last updated 10 years ago and the header in that .py file says it's for Blender version 2.70 so it's very unlikely that they will work with modern versions of Blender, particularly version 4 onwards because the Blender APIs and Python versions have changed over the years. In any case we can't help with third-party addons as this Q&A site can only help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons.

Comment: Further checking shows a more recent YT video [here](https://youtu.be/hpqPjnbyITw) that uses a different site to download an importer. Try that one!

Comment: Hi John. I checked the link and unfortunately it didn't work. For some reason after I try to install the .zip file it does not appear on the add-ons to enable it.  I will keep searching. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Might be worth asking on the [Sketchup Community](https://forums.sketchup.com/) forum...